# Как переписать поля, когда выполняешь COPY FROM для экспорта данных из CSV?

Tags: csv, nosql, cassandra

Можно ли **переписать** существующие строки, выполняя команду `COPY FROM` (из CSV),
или как предварительно **полностью удалить** строки из целевой БД?

Когда я выполняю `COPY FROM` для существующих строк, значения полей суммируются.

Также не получается полностью `DELETE` строки:
хотя сначала кажется, что команда удаляет строки,
но после выполнения `COPY FROM` данные продолжают увеличиваться с прежнего значения.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521180/how-to-overwrite-fields-when-you-copy-from-data

Comment: Копируйте во временное хранилище. Затем удалите из основного что надо удалить. Затем копируйте из временного в основное.

Comment: @Akina В том-то и дело, что значения полей-счётчиков каком-то образом сохраняются даже при удалении строк. Это же упомянуто в постановке проблемы.

Comment: Наверное, я не понимаю, о каких именно счётчиках речь... если о некоем уникальном индексе типа автоинкремента - то после копирования во временное хранилище существующие записи надо не удалять и записывать новые, а обновлять, не затрагивая это самое поле.

Comment: @Akina Речь о полях с `data_type: counter` – они каким-то образом сохраняют своё состояние даже при удалении самой строки, которая их, собственно, содержит.